# generating *interesting* strings at random in Java

Tags: java, string, random, scalacheck

I've been using ScalaCheck for automatic unit testing. Its default String generator (i.e., its default `Arbitrary[String]` instance) is a little **too** powerful, generally producing an unreadable jumble made up mainly of characters I'm not trying to support and my system can't even render.

I've set out to create some more `Arbitrary[String]` instances, and am trying to find out what's out there.
Here are some examples of String classes that would be helpful for testing:

- basic multilingual plane strings
- astral strings
- latinate strings (including extensions a/b)
- French words
- left-to-right language strings
- right-to-left language strings
- Chinese sentences
- "web strings" (strings drawn from a character set that constitutes 99.9999% of web content)
- use your imagination ...

Are there libraries out there that can make these, or similar strings, at random?

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a different approach. All of your examples map to blocks of characters in Unicode. See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm Just pick the blocks you like, and then generate random strings that are limited to those ranges.

```
int count = 10;
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
Random rand = new Random(0);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  char ch = rand.nextInt(numCharsInRange) + firstCharInRange;
  out.append(ch);
}
return out.toString();
```

Another approach would be to grab random snippets of pre-composed text from different languages. You can grab some here: http://www.unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html Just look at the translations.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RandomStringUtils.random(10, true, false)
```

The parameters are as follows: `int count, boolean letters, boolean numbers`

You will need to import `org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;`